# My function Register catches more mistakes, in Django framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a problem:
In my function `register()` I use `FormRegistration` of Django and my custom `ProfilForm`, but I cannot display the different errors (username not unique, passwords do not match, ...).

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreate(request.POST)
        form2 = ProfilForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            form2 = form2.save(commit=False)
            form2.user = user
            form2.skill = form2.cleaned_data.get('skill')
            form2.board = form2.cleaned_data.get('board')
            form2.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/accueil')
    else:
        form = UserCreate()
        form2 = ProfilForm()

    return render(
        request,
        'registration/register.html',
        {'form2': form2},
        {'form': form})
```

This is my template register.html for displaying errors :

```
{% if form.errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <p><strong>Error !</strong> <p>There was a problem while trying to register, check your fields.</p></p>
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% if form.errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <p><strong>Error !</strong> <p>{{ form.username.errors|striptags }}</p></p>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. The line `form2 = form2.save(commit=False)` does not look right; you should assign the output of `save()` to another variable, but right now you are just overriding `form2`.
2. The last return statement should only get one `dict` for context:

   Change you code

   ```
   return render(
       request,
       'registration/register.html',
       {'form2': form2},
       {'form': form})
   ```

   to

   ```
   return render(
       request,
       'registration/register.html',
       {'form2': form2, 'form': form})
   ```

Comment: Thanks sir, you at resolve my problem. Just a last question, i use django "UserCreationForm" , why the email adress is not "unique" ? when I create new user with an email which already exists, it works..,  the unique for "username" it's ok, but not email, you have a solution for me please ?

Comment: If you look at the [source of Djangos `User` model](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L309), `email` is not marked as unique. I don't know a short solution for that, but you could post another question for that and maybe someone knows a solution.